# Cypress automation with headless CMS

Tags: graphql, cypress, headless-cms

I am working on project website which uses headless cms with graphql to implement the cypress tests. The website contents like articles/blogs changes based what is being updated in CMS. Anyone has experience here where can i look for similar project automation ?

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) is the best choice nowadays, you can start with [Gatsby Starter for Blogs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/).

**Features**

- Basic setup for a full-featured blog
- Support for an RSS feed
- Google Analytics support
- Automatic optimization of images in Markdown posts
- Support for code syntax highlighting
- Includes plugins for easy, beautiful typography
- Includes React Helmet to allow editing site meta tags
- Includes plugins for offline support out of the box